# Expression for nano scale crack propogation

Tags: geometry, physics

The following image is of a nano-scale self replicating crack on a thin film/substrate pair. I want to construct a "position" function for the crack front's propagation. So far the only way I can think to achieve this is with a piece wise function, but I am not sure. Does anyone have an idea of how to define this shape as a continuous function?

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztvfH.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need a parametric form, since the curve is multi-valued both along the horizontal axis and the vertical axis.
I started from 
$$x=\sin(t)\\y=t$$
to get

[image]

Then I noted that as you go away from the center the points are moved upwards, so I added a term proportional to $x^2$
$$x=\sin(t)\\y=t+3x^2$$ and I get

[image]

You can now play with some parameters, or the exact functional representation for $y$

Comment: Oh thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: just mark the question as answered